# How to hide "signed by" in Outlook 2016

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016

Outlook wastes huge amount of visual space in general.  I've optimized quite a bit and I'm resigned to the fact that there is no way to hide the header in the reading pane, but there's one thing I can't seem to get rid of and would like to:  the "signed by" garbage in the message reading pane.

[image]

Comment: You cannot. The only way not to be notified the email is actually digitally signed is not to signed it in the first place.  You might be able to write an add-on to suppress the information, but how you would do that, is beyond the scope of a Superuser question in my opinion since it wouldn't be easy and it would involved some pretty advanced programming.

Comment: Well, that's poo.  The fact that I now work for a company with a microsoft stack is the bane of my existence :/  Thanks tho Ramhound